# How I can place further constraints upon foreign key?

Tags: foreign-key, constraint, sql-server-2022

In sql server I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.dbo.files (
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    folder bigint NULL,
    [type] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK ([type] IN('FILE','FOLDER')) DEFAULT 'FOLDER'
    CONSTRAINT PK__category__3213E83FDB19A582 PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES mydb.dbo.files(id)
);
```

And I want the column folder to receive ids from `files` table that also have in the column `type` the value `FOLDER`. Can I do it with a constraint?

In order words I want the foreign key `folder_fk` to reference a file that has `type` `FOLDER`.

To be much more clear I try to do:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.dbo.files (
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    folder bigint NULL,
    [type] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK ([type] IN('FILE','FOLDER')) DEFAULT 'FOLDER'
    CONSTRAINT PK__category__3213E83FDB19A582 PRIMARY KEY (id),
-- Idk whether syntax is correct I just want to showcase what I try to achieve
    CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES mydb.dbo.files(id) HAVING `type` = "FOLDER"
);
```

Comment: Describe the system which you want to model. *`CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES delta.dbo.files(id)`* Your FK constraint looks strange (a folder is a child of a file in another table).

Comment: What I want is to reference foreign key `folder_fk` to a record that has `type` `FOLDER` and I do not know how.

Comment: It seems the constraints use 3-part names to reference objects in different databases. Objects must be in the same database for referential constraints.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.

You can't use a filtered unique index as the target for a foreign key, and unlike some DBs you can't have multiple NULLs in a non-filtered unique index, so you can't use an index on a computed column containing `CASE WHEN type='FOLDER' THEN id ELSE NULL END`.

You could use a negative value for non-folders and add an extra constraint on that, like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.files (
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    folder bigint NULL CHECK (folder>-1),
    [type] nvarchar(10) NOT NULL CHECK ([type] IN('FILE','FOLDER')) DEFAULT 'FOLDER',
    folder_id AS CASE WHEN [type]='FOLDER' THEN id ELSE -id END PERSISTED UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT PK_files PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id),
    CONSTRAINT folder_fk FOREIGN KEY (folder) REFERENCES dbo.files(folder_id)
);
```

This feels more than a little dirty due to the extra persisted computed column containing a mix of duplicated data (the folder id values) and essentially meaningless data (the negative values for files) but it achieves the constraints you want.

---

<sub>**Side note:** I also clustered your PK, or your table is a less efficient heap.</sub>